# Error: Element type "apex:inputText" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: visualforce, inputtext

I am getting the error  `Element type "apex:inputText" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".` when using `<apex:inputText>`.

VF Markup

```
<apex:page controller="awardsClassExperiment" lightningStyleSheets="true">
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
    <!--Add scholarship to pageBlockTable-->
    <apex:pageBlockButtons>
      <apex:commandButton action="{!add_recipient}" value="Add Recipient"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    <!-- User inputs fields -->
    <apex:inputText value="{!currentSubmission.recipient.Name"} label="First Name"/>
    <apex:inputText value="{!currentSubmission.recipient.Last_Name__c"} label ="Last Name"/>
    <apex:inputText value="{!currentSubmission.recipient.School__c}" label="School"/>
    <apex:inputText value="{!currentSubmission.Specialty__c"} label="Specialty"/>
    <apex:inputText value="{!currentSubmission.scholarship.Award__c"} label="Award"/>

    </apex:pageBlock>
    
    <!-- Record List-->
    <apex:pageBlock title="Your Added Scholarships">
        <apex:pageBlockTable> id="Recipients" value="{!Submissions}" var="Recipient">
            <apex:column headerValue="First Name" value="{!Recipient.Recipient.Name}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Last Name" value="{!Recipient.Recipient.Last_Name__c}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="School__c" value="{!Recipient.Recipient.School__c}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Award" value="{!Recipient.Scholarship.Award__c}"/>

        </apexPageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I am not sure what is the issue here as I used `<` and `/>` for all `<apex:inputText>` tags.

Comment: Looks to me like you have several close curly braces outside of the quoted attribute value. Like `value="{!currentSubmission.recipient.Last_Name__c"}`. Is that a typo, or does it really exist in your visualforce page?

Comment: @DerekF You should add that answer, it is most likely correct.

Comment: Nice catch. Thanks. Wrote this in VS so didn't notice it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like there are issues in your merge syntax here.

I count 3 locations where the closing curly bracket comes after the closing quote

```html
<apex:inputText value="{!currentSubmission.recipient.Name"} label="First Name"/>
<apex:inputText value="{!currentSubmission.recipient.Last_Name__c"} label ="Last Name"/> <!-- first instance -->
<apex:inputText value="{!currentSubmission.recipient.School__c}" label="School"/>
<apex:inputText value="{!currentSubmission.Specialty__c"} label="Specialty"/> <!-- second instance -->
<apex:inputText value="{!currentSubmission.scholarship.Award__c"} label="Award"/> <!-- third instance -->
```

The entire merge expression should be contained in the attribute value (enclosed by quotes).

i.e. `value="{!expression"}` is wrong, and `value="{!expression}"` is right.